# Plugin working on my local installation but Cannot be activated online

Tags: plugin-development

Good Day Everyone,

I want to test my Plugin online on my real website but I don't know why, the following line would give an error, when on my local installation everything works perfectly. (I tried to deactivate and reactivate on my local install and I don't get the error).

Both are using the latest version of WordPress (4.2.2)

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'plugin_jquery');
function plugin_jquery()
{
    if (!is_admin())
        wp_enqueue_script('plugin-jquery', plugins_url('js/plugin_regpage.js', __FILE__), ['jquery'], true);

    wp_enqueue_style(
        'plugin-regpage-css',
         plugins_url('css/plugin_regpage.css', __FILE__)
    );
}
```

I get:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in
>   html/wp-content/plugins/plugin/plugin.php on line 49

Why would a bracket make a problem online and not locally?

Comment: The new short array syntax (`[]`) is only avaible from PHP 5.4.

Comment: Online version is less than PHP 5.4 while offline is bigger than PHP5.4 ;-)

Comment: Hmmmmmmmm... Let me have a look at that ;-) You might have put your finger on it... How would I fix it then :-/

Comment: And... What would be the "proper" way to write it then? Is it me that made a "mistake" in my writing? Or the problem is on my server as it should be higher than 5.4? Should I re-write my code to make it available to more people?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code, it is server side. Your host is using an outdated PHP version which can have a security impact to you as support for PHP 5.3 was dropped a year ago. To avoid this issue, just use the old array syntax (`array()`) instead of the new array syntax

Comment: Just to make sure proper way to replace ['jquery'] would be array('jquery') ? And yes I confirmed... Freakin' GoDaddy uses 5.2 and 5.3 ><... So as you said... since it's Outdated...I should just rewrite my code for my website and leave the brackets for my plugin when I share it on the WordPress site?

Comment: Before you do anything, ask godaddy to update their php version to atleast 5.4. Just remember, if you are going to share your plugin, make sure to note minimum PHP version, people will try to skin you for breaking their site ;-)

Comment: Good point... :-/ I'm not sure 1 user will make it though... But I will try thanks ... I'll be back on that shortly... Or I will simply change my provider... (which I've been thinking for a while now)....

Comment: O yes, `array( 'jquery' )` is correct

Comment: Thanks at least this way I will be able to test it properly for the time being... I will also contact them as 5.3 is EOL since 9 months already...

Comment: @PieterGoosen can you add an official answer? I'll give you credits for it... I confirmed and fix the problem. It seems that GoDaddy doesn't update their old subscription and you have to change plans for things like that to happen, but you were spot on I was on 5.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with your PHP versions on your local and live install.

The new short array syntax (`[]`) was implemented in PHP 5.4. This tells you that your PHP version on your local install is at least PHP 5.4 and your live install has a version older than that. The new short array syntax will lead to a PHP error in older versions as it is invalid PHP in the older versions.

### SOLUTION

As PHP 5.3 was EOL'ed almost a year ago, it is a very good and security wise idea to ask your host to upgrade their PHP version to atleast PHP 5.4. Alternatively, you can change your new short array syntax back to the old array syntax.

```
['jquery']
```

then becomes

```
array( 'jquery' )
```